# SSL Exception with ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer4 on Ubuntu

Tags: identityserver4, ubuntu-18.04, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an ASP.NET Core application with an Angular 7 SPA using IdentityServer4 with OAuth 2.0 resource owner password grant with Entity Framework storage. This code works on Windows using IIS and I'm trying to transition my development to Ubuntu.  I have the same error on Windows with Kestrel.

I am having issues with the self signed certificates <strike>on Ubuntu</strike> in Kestrel.  When I debug the application Chrome shows the certificate as valid, however, when the user attempts to authenticate I receive an SSL error that the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I think this is an SSL config issue, but I've been struggling for days and have been unable to resolve this.

I followed the directions here https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/develop-locally-with-https-self-signed-certificates-and-asp-net-core to create my dev certs.

IdentityServerConfig.cs:

```cs
    public class IdentityServerConfig
    {
        // Identity resources (used by UserInfo endpoint).
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            // http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/topics/resources.html#defining-custom-identity-resources

            // define which user claims should be included in the identity token 
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                // scopes
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResource("roles", new List<string> { JwtClaimTypes.Role })
            };
        }

        // Api resources.
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            // http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/topics/resources.html#defining-api-resources
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("WebAPI") {
                    // include the following using claims in access token (in addition to subject id)
                    UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Role }
                }
            };
        }

        // Clients want to access resources.
        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            // http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/topics/clients.html
            // Clients credentials.
            return new List<Client>
            {
                // http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/client.html.
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "AngularSPA",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword, // Resource Owner Password Credential grant.
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false, // This client does not need a secret to request tokens from the token endpoint.

                    AllowedScopes = {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId, // For UserInfo endpoint.
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "roles",
                        "WebAPI"
                    },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true, // For refresh token.
                    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```cs
            // Adds IdentityServer.
            var identiyServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    // https://github.com/robisim74/AngularSPAWebAPI/blob/master/Startup.cs#L30
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                })
                .AddSigningCredential(cert)
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                // To configure IdentityServer to use EntityFramework (EF) as the storage mechanism for configuration data (rather than using the in-memory implementations),
                // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityServerConfig.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerConfig.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerConfig.GetClients())
                .AddAspNetIdentity<AppUser>();  

services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    if (currentEnvironment.IsProduction())
                    {
                        options.Authority = "https://yyy/";
                    }
                    else if (currentEnvironment.IsStaging())
                    {
                        options.Authority = "https://xxx/";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
                    }

                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ApiName = "WebAPI";
                });
```

This is the relevant config:

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "HTTP" : {
        "Url": "http://*:5000"
      },
      "HTTPS": {
        "Url": "https://*:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "../SSL/DevCert.pfx",
          "Password": "fFQ3#8&q-KG",
          "AllowInvalid":"true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And the stack trace:

```
2019/05/21 10:18:46.799|INFO|36|Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/connect/userinfo   |Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Protocol=HTTP/1.1, Method=GET, ContentType=, ContentLength=, Scheme=https, Host=localhost:5001, PathBase=, Path=/connect/userinfo, QueryString=, EventId_Id=1, EventId_Name=, EventId=1
2019/05/21 10:18:46.958|ERROR|37|Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler|EventId_Id=3, EventId_Name=, EventId=3
2019/05/21 10:18:47.009|ERROR|37|An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() in C:\local\identity\server4\AccessTokenValidation\src\IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.cs:line 61
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\src\Hosting\BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware|EventId_Id=1, EventId_Name=UnhandledException, EventId=UnhandledException
```

Comment: If you remove `"AllowInvalid":"true"` from your config, does the app run?

Comment: Removing AllowInvalid has no effect, I get the same error.

Comment: DId you solved this issue? I am facing same error.

Comment: Maybe unsupported TLS ?